# setting titleView only works with root controller

Tags: swift

I have a ViewController that is the root Controller of a navigation controller.
In the viewDidLoad() i set a custom titleView:

```
let titleView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TitleView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? TitleView
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = titleView
```

this works fine, but now i push a new instance of the same view controller to the navigation controller and here it doesn't work. Instead i get the default title
do i have to use something else instead of topItem?

Comment: Try this ```self.navigationItem.titleView = ....```

Answer (score 0):

```
let titleView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TitleView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? TitleView
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = titleView
```

instead

```
let titleView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TitleView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? TitleView
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

[image]